# создание приложения android для ТСД, с использованием лазерного сканера

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Я хочу создать приложение для android, которое будет считывать QR код, это легко) но мне нужно данное приложение использовать на ТСД АТОЛ Smart.Lite, на нем нет камеры.. как мне в данном приложении использовать не камеру, а лазерный сканер встроенный в ТСД АТОЛ Smart.Lite? Подскажите какие либо библиотеки, или полезную литературу, ну а в идеале скиньте кусок кода реализующий данную возможность) разработку буду делать на Android Studio

Comment: Попробуйте обратится к АТОЛу. Наверняка у них есть соответствующий SDK.

Comment: Я уже обратился, но ответа пока не дают, может кто-либо и присутствующих разработчиков знает ответ)

Comment: Вполне возможно, но вероятность получить нужные сведения от АТОЛа всё равно выше. Всё-таки не каждый Android разработчик работает с кассой или ТСД.

Comment: http://fs.atol.ru/_layouts/15/atol.templates/Handlers/FileHandler.ashx?guid=67a78c6b-1933-4d1d-b5eb-3e1c16fae071&webUrl

Comment: Вот тот самый SDK о котором вы говорили)

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как данный SDK добавить в мое приложение?

Comment: В архиве вроде есть инструкция, как пользоваться. В крайнем случае у Вас наверняка есть контакты их техподдержки.

Comment: здесь есть sdk, но хз работает ли оно http://files.atol.ru/temp/%D0%A2%D0%A1%D0%94%20%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%9B%20SMART.Lite/Scan_SDK.rar

Comment: написано через жопу, конечно